# Удаление элемента массива по индексу

Tags: c++

Очень простенькая, но не получается.

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int a[3000];
    int i, n, nm;

    cout << "press the number" << "\n";
    cin >> n;
    for (i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
        a[i] = rand() % 401 - 200;
        cout << a[i] << " ";
    }
    cout << "\n";

    system("PAUSE");
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Нужно из этого массива сделать удаление элемента массива по индексу.

Comment: "press the number" -- как-то не очень звучит :)

Answer (score 6):

Как-то уж всё совсем печально.

Динамически память не выделяете, `STL` не используете и режущий глаз вызов `system("PAUSE");`.

Судя по всему, много элементов удалять не придётся, а потому просто смещаете все элементы, кроме удаляемого, на 1 влево и уменьшаете длину массива на 1.

Например:

```
k - нужный индекс
for (long i = k; i < n; ++i)
{
  a[i] = a[i + 1];
}
--n;
```

Как-то так.

p.s. В C/C++ индексация массивов идёт с нуля. На будущее ;)

Comment: Уточните, в массиве n или n+1 (как у автора вопроса) элементов?

n+1 как-то глаз режет, а если n, то за границу вылазите.

Comment: @avp n элементов, но мы "думаем", что индексация идёт с 1, как у ТС.
И да, я согласен, это действительо глаз режет.
p.s. Ну или, если быть кэпом, 3000 элементов.

Answer (score -1):

Если размер массива не большой можно делать проще.
Создаёшь еще один массив и добавляешь в него элементы кроме удаляемого 
далее присваиваешь первому массиву значения второго.

Делал так на GDScript всё работает

Answer (score -2):

это выглядит примерно так. ответ выше неправильный, потому что мы идем от индекса того элемента,которого на нужно удалить до длины массива-1 (потому что если бы мы шли до длины массива, возник бы RT).

```
int length = 5;
int array[length] = {23, 3,51, 87,90};
int index = 3;

cout << "Исходный массив: ";
for(int i = 0; i < length; ++i)
     cout << array[i] << " ";
cout << endl;

**index--;  //т.к. индексация с нуля
for(int i = index; i < length-1;++i)
    array[i] = array[i+1];
length--;**

cout << "Массив, после удаление 3-его элемента: ";
for(int i = 0; i < length; ++i)
     cout << array[i] << " ";
```